# python3.9 quit unexpectedly (segmentation fault) on Monterey M1

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, python-3.9, macos-monterey

Today I was running a python script from terminal and I can't anymore:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  python3.9 script_name.py
```

The window with more details says:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               python3.9 [1420]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python3.9
Identifier:            python3.9
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [1404]
Responsible:           Terminal [586]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-06-27 13:21:57.6610 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.6.1 (21G217)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C37BD5BC-29E8-9550-85BB-8E2EC972B657


Time Awake Since Boot: 4100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffffe00000375
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0xfffffffe00000375
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1420]

VM Region Info: 0xfffffffe00000375 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 18446638511466480502  
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO (reserved)   600018000000-600020000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   python3.9                              0x102b19b94 PyBuffer_Release + 24
1   CoreGraphics                           0x1925aad48 data_release_info + 40
2   CoreGraphics                           0x1925aad48 data_release_info + 40
3   CoreGraphics                           0x192564f5c data_provider_finalize + 60
4   CoreGraphics                           0x192531e6c data_provider_retain_count + 96
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18d13f134 _CFRelease + 1264
6   CoreGraphics                           0x19258c210 image_finalize + 100
7   CoreFoundation                         0x18d13ed2c _CFRelease + 232
8   CoreGraphics                           0x1925cdf74 CG::DisplayListResourceImage::~DisplayListResourceImage() + 56
9   CoreGraphics                           0x1925cdf24 CG::DisplayListResourceImage::~DisplayListResourceImage() + 16
10  CoreGraphics                           0x19278a994 std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared() + 84
11  CoreGraphics                           0x1928ecff4 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::shared_ptr<CG::DisplayListResourceImage>, CG::CompareResourceImage, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<CG::DisplayListResourceImage> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::shared_ptr<CG::DisplayListResourceImage>, void*>*) + 60
12  CoreGraphics                           0x1925cda94 CG::DisplayList::~DisplayList() + 304
13  CoreFoundation                         0x18d13ed2c _CFRelease + 232
14  CoreFoundation                         0x18d002c10 __RELEASE_OBJECTS_IN_THE_ARRAY__ + 116
15  CoreFoundation                         0x18d002b48 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 276
16  CoreGraphics                           0x1925cb888 CG::DisplayListRecorder::~DisplayListRecorder() + 60
17  CoreGraphics                           0x1925cb834 CG::DisplayListRecorder::~DisplayListRecorder() + 16
18  CoreGraphics                           0x192556008 CGContextDelegateFinalize + 60
19  CoreFoundation                         0x18d13ecfc _CFRelease + 184
20  CoreGraphics                           0x192555f70 context_reclaim + 56
21  CoreFoundation                         0x18d13ecfc _CFRelease + 184
22  AppKit                                 0x18fd26d90 -[NSCGSContext _invalidate] + 52
23  AppKit                                 0x18fd26d30 -[NSCGSContext dealloc] + 36
24  AppKit                                 0x18fd26cfc -[NSBitmapGraphicsContext dealloc] + 68
25  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18ce252b4 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
26  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18ce21b34 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 212
27  QuartzCore                             0x19404e6a0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 580
28  QuartzCore                             0x193ee34cc CA::Transaction::commit() + 704
29  AppKit                                 0x18fd3569c __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 304
30  AppKit                                 0x19049a758 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 64
31  CoreFoundation                         0x18d0641a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
32  CoreFoundation                         0x18d063ff4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 592
33  CoreFoundation                         0x18d063528 __CFRunLoopRun + 772
34  CoreFoundation                         0x18d062a84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
35  HIToolbox                              0x195ca6338 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
36  HIToolbox                              0x195ca5fc4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 324
37  HIToolbox                              0x195ca5e68 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
38  AppKit                                 0x18fbca51c _DPSNextEvent + 860
39  AppKit                                 0x18fbc8e14 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1328
40  AppKit                                 0x18fbbafe0 -[NSApplication run] + 596
41  _macosx.cpython-39-darwin.so           0x1048a4bac show + 184
42  python3.9                              0x102b992f8 cfunction_vectorcall_NOARGS + 96
43  python3.9                              0x102c62874 call_function + 128
44  python3.9                              0x102c5ba24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23340
45  python3.9                              0x102b3cea8 function_code_fastcall + 168
46  python3.9                              0x102c62874 call_function + 128
47  python3.9                              0x102c5ba24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23340
48  python3.9                              0x102c54938 _PyEval_EvalCode + 496
49  python3.9                              0x102b3cdc4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
50  python3.9                              0x102c56790 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2200
51  python3.9                              0x102c54938 _PyEval_EvalCode + 496
52  python3.9                              0x102b3cdc4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
53  python3.9                              0x102b40210 method_vectorcall + 388
54  python3.9                              0x102c56790 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2200
55  python3.9                              0x102c54938 _PyEval_EvalCode + 496
56  python3.9                              0x102b3cdc4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
57  python3.9                              0x102c62874 call_function + 128
58  python3.9                              0x102c5ba24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23340
59  python3.9                              0x102c54938 _PyEval_EvalCode + 496
60  python3.9                              0x102cb8948 pyrun_file + 312
61  python3.9                              0x102cb80ac pyrun_simple_file + 372
62  python3.9                              0x102cb7ed8 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 120
63  python3.9                              0x102cdeff8 pymain_run_file + 300
64  python3.9                              0x102cde3b4 pymain_run_python + 360
65  python3.9                              0x102cde1f4 Py_RunMain + 40
66  python3.9                              0x102cdfb74 pymain_main + 72
67  python3.9                              0x102ad9fd0 main + 56
68  dyld                                   0x1030ed08c start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 2:
0   libomp.dylib                           0x10419549c kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1748
1   libomp.dylib                           0x104195328 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1376
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
3   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
4   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
5   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18cf5a9b8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf95108 cthread_yield + 20
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104195450 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1672
3   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
4   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
5   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
6   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libomp.dylib                           0x104174510 kmp_flag_native<unsigned long long, (flag_type)1, true>::notdone_check() + 0
1   libomp.dylib                           0x104195328 kmp_flag_64<false, true>::wait(kmp_info*, int, void*) + 1376
2   libomp.dylib                           0x104190560 __kmp_hyper_barrier_release(barrier_type, kmp_info*, int, int, int, void*) + 184
3   libomp.dylib                           0x1041940e8 __kmp_fork_barrier(int, int) + 628
4   libomp.dylib                           0x104170e14 __kmp_launch_thread + 340
5   libomp.dylib                           0x1041af00c __kmp_launch_worker(void*) + 280
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9826c _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf9308c thread_start + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf93078 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf93078 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18cf93078 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000016d3264f0   x1: 0x0000000148000000   x2: 0x0000000000d6d800   x3: 0x000000018cda704c
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000004   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000193f217fc
    x8: 0x00000001048a2ea8   x9: 0x00000000ffffffff  x10: 0x00000000ff000000  x11: 0x007ffffffffffff8
   x12: 0x000000000000016e  x13: 0x00000000abb50144  x14: 0x00000000abd50800  x15: 0x00000000000002a1
   x16: 0x0000000102b19b7c  x17: 0x00000001e59f5c20  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0xfffffffe0000036d
   x20: 0x000000016d3264f0  x21: 0xffffffffffffffff  x22: 0x00000001e31c4000  x23: 0xffffffffff810380
   x24: 0x00000001e31bce80  x25: 0x0000000100000000  x26: 0xffffffff00000000  x27: 0x000000013dc6e678
   x28: 0x00000001e3339000   fp: 0x000000016d327670   lr: 0x00000001925aad48
    sp: 0x000000016d327660   pc: 0x0000000102b19b94 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0xfffffffe00000375  esr: 0x92000004 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x102ad4000 -        0x102dfffff python3.9 (*) <f9348a2c-0432-3f11-98a7-f9481ff7e623> /Users/USER/*/python3.9
       0x192526000 -        0x192b33fff com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0) <790514ae-01b1-3cd7-a6cb-75224f9d6c56> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
       0x18cfe0000 -        0x18d526fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <fc3c193d-0cdb-3569-9f0e-bd2507ca1dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x18fb89000 -        0x190a41fff com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <5ece5db5-a167-3ab1-a1cf-af442beecea6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
       0x18ce17000 -        0x18ce54fff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <ec96f0fa-6341-3e1d-be54-49b544e17f7d> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x193ee1000 -        0x19420cfff com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11) <239ccbf7-85b5-3a4c-bf04-d50cf65feaea> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
       0x195c74000 -        0x195fa7fff com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1) <aaf900bd-bfb6-3af0-a8d3-e24bbe1d57f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
       0x10489c000 -        0x1048a7fff _macosx.cpython-39-darwin.so (*) <ab6da419-f098-30ae-959f-b44482854f72> /Users/USER/*/_macosx.cpython-39-darwin.so
       0x1030e8000 -        0x103147fff dyld (*) <24d09537-e51b-350e-b59e-181c9d94d291> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x18cf59000 -        0x18cf90fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <dbf55fdd-2b9b-3701-93b6-7a3ce359bd0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x18cf91000 -        0x18cf9dfff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <63c4eef9-69a5-38b1-996e-8d31b66a051d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x104150000 -        0x1041d7fff libomp.dylib (*) <f53b1e01-af16-30fc-8690-f7b131eb6ce5> /Users/USER/*/libomp.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=824.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=824.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=2.1G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2.1G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               128K        1 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG image                           272K        8 
ColorSync                          576K       25 
CoreAnimation                     13.6M        7 
CoreGraphics                        16K        1 
CoreUI image data                  512K        5 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           312.2M       58 
MALLOC guard page                  192K        9 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         960.0M        8         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                        208K       13 
Stack                             89.7M       13 
VM_ALLOCATE                      137.8M      173 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)           256.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__AUTH                            1804K      151 
__AUTH_CONST                       9.8M      293 
__CTF                               756        1 
__DATA                            11.5M      371 
__DATA_CONST                      11.5M      380 
__DATA_DIRTY                       593K      100 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       583.0M       90 
__OBJC_CONST                      1263K      128 
__OBJC_RO                         83.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3168K        1 
__TEXT                           241.3M      394 
__UNICODE                          592K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                       67.7M       15 
shared memory                      848K       14 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              3.1G     2269 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.5G     2269
```

I don't remember I have installed any software or changed any path since the last time the same script was launched fine. I've looked around and some similar issues have to do with a $pythonpath (not defined in my case). It strikes me that the full report says:

```
Version:               ???
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to upgrade `matplotlib`:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I found a similar issue and fix [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18953).